# modx убрать классы которые приписывает pdoPage

Tags: html, css, cms, modx, pdotools

использую pdoPage с пагинацией для вывода статей. И к моим ссылкам добавляются чужие классы!
Вопрос: "КАК ИХ УБРАТЬ?"
А именно классы: page-item, page-link
Спасибо

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <ul class="pages">
    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">Первая</a></li>
    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="our-products.html">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="our-products.html?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="our-products.html?page=2">Последняя</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо переопределить базовые чанки `tplPage`, `tplPageActive` и другие по необходимости, смотрите документацию: https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdopage

Сейчас вы используете классы и чанки,прописанные по умолчанию. Где их можно увидеть:
найдите в Элементах MODX сниппет pdoPage, откройте вкладку "Свойства".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Рад был помочь. Если ответ помог вам, отмечайте его флажком, это поможет другим пользователям в дальнейшем.